# D3 show values as label on right axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am doing a dot plot in D3 and I want to add the values along a right Y axis. I have done this before in many charts, adding labels is straightforward, but for some reason this particular chart is giving a lot of problems.

I cant get the values of the dots to show on the right axis.

[jsfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/m5skxd6o/)
The chart appears on click.

The relevant code for the value labels attached to the right axis:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 10) + " ,0)")    
    .call(yAxis1)
    .selectAll('text')
    .text(function(d){ return xScale(d.value); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an ordinal axis you are binding your domain values to the axis ticks.  So, the scale domain should be:

```
var yScale1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.value; })) //<-- use '.value'
    .rangeRoundPoints([0, height]);
```

Then your y-axis call just becomes:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 10) + " ,0)")  
  .call(yAxis1);
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5skxd6o/4/).

Comment: Mark, this works. However, in my app, in many of the charts, the values dont align correctly. I am not sure why.

Comment: Maybe the problem is instead of using a scale and axis, I should position labels.

Comment: I ended up just using labels. Using an axis was not the right way to do this.